# Step-by-step Install Iframely

Tags: node.js, oembed

I wan to using this oembed https://github.com/itteco/iframely but I dont know how to setup .

I already try follow this documentation to setup https://github.com/itteco/iframely/blob/master/docs/SETUP.md .

What should i do after run command `"node server"` ?

Can some one tell step-by-step to use this oembed ?

Comment: Did you ever get the self-hosted Iframely parser working to your liking? I'd love to pick your brain over it. There's very little documentation around it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently doing the same and am also stuck (but at a later stage!) but hopefully this will help someone even if you have already moved on - I realise this is a very old question!

If you have succeeded in running `npm install` for iframely then after you run `node server` you should get a message similar to below:

```
Using cache engine: node-cache
No local whitelist file detected...
Loading whitelist from http://iframely.com/qa/whitelist.json
Iframely plugins loaded:
   - custom domains: 246
   - generic & meta: 0

Starting Iframely...
Base URL for embeds that require hosted renders: http://yourdomain.com

Iframely listening on port 8061
 - support@iframely.com - if you need help
 - twitter.com/iframely - news & updates
 - github.com/itteco/iframely - star & contribute
Whitelist activated. Domains, including blacklisted: 2005
```

Then you simply use a browser or a JSON tool to make the request from your server at the port above (8601 in my case):

```
GET http://localhost:8601/iframely?url=<your URL-encoded URL here>
```

You should receive a response in JSON format. The problem I am having is that I'm getting what looks to be an incomplete response with only meta-data but I will need to work that out myself / ask another question on SO for that...Anyway, here's what my JSON response looks like...a bit bare but hopefully you get the idea at least:

```
{
meta: 
    {
    canonical: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=32&v=4sFuULOY5ik"
    }
    links: [0]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get self-hosted Iframely working to your liking? I'd love to ask a few questions if so. There's hardly any documentation around it online.

Comment: Hey @Dent7777 no - I'm afraid I moved my project in a different direction all those years ago. Good luck!

Comment: After some issues with AWS's ECS, after which we moved to a docker container hosted in EC2, our team managed to get the parser up and running. So far, it seems like a great solution. I managed to get past the issues I wanted to talk to you about.